# Should the storage device be stopped before using xfs_growfs?

Tags: filesystems, disk, xfs

My cloud server has an external device formatted as XFS. After expanding the volume, I will need to run the command:

```
$ sudo xfs_growfs /dev/sdb
```

Since it is critical for a service to keep writing on the device, would it be possible to run `xfs_growfs` without stopping the service? The usual "safe" way is to stop the service, run `xfs_growfs`, then start the service again. I was just wondering if stopping the service is really needed, or if `xfs_growfs` was designed to be able to resize even when reads and writes on the disk is ongoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xfs_growfs` works online, no need to stop anything, no problem at all.

As long as the larger `/dev/sdb` device size is detected properly, and you're actually using XFS on full disk instead of a partition, you can grow it directly. If there are partitions involved, you have to grow the partition first.